# ¿Cómo reducir la longitud de un mongoID existente?

Tags: mongodb

> An ObjectId in MongoDB is a 12-byte BSON type. In the 12-byte
>   structure, the first 4 bytes of the ObjectId represent the time in
>   seconds since the UNIX epoch. The next 3 bytes of the ObjectId
>   represent the machine identifier. The next 2 bytes of the ObjectId
>   represent the process ID. And the last 3 bytes of the ObjectId
>   represent a random counter value.
>
> These 12 bytes altogether uniquely identifies a document within the
>   MongoDB collection and serves as a primary key for that document.
>   ObjectId is the default value of _id field of each document and its
>   complexity helps to fetch a unique _id field for a particular document
>   in the MongoDB.

Un cliente desea usar el mismo identificador, pero por alguna razón no puede usar el identificador largo de 5813eed6e6893b80c9ae5bba 24 caracteres, así que en un momento de desesperación, el líder de equipo cortó los primeros 4 dígitos 5813 - eed6e6893b80c9ae5bba, pero no sé qué tan buena idea es esta y cuál es la probabilidad de colisión si se aplica esta idea, asumimos que los 4 primeros dígitos corresponden a "la parte de valor de contador aleatorio" como se expresa en los documentos.

Entonces, mi pregunta es ¿cuál es la probabilidad de colisión de este id cortado eed6e6893b80c9ae5bba? Si es una mala idea, ¿cómo convertir el ID de mongo en un equivalente de 20 caracteres que pueda volver a convertir a 24 caracteres?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el siguiente link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055102/how-to-make-a-20-char-id-with-a-24-char-objectid  podría servirte de ayuda para lo que buscas.